# How to invoke the overloaded operator in a derived classes, rather than the base, when pointed to as base in a collection

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-overloading, virtual

As the title suggests, I am trying to invoke overloaded operators in derived classes, while all of the objects are in a collection of type "pointer to base". In this case, `std::array<A*, #>`. I think that the code examples will make my situation more clear.

classes.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
        
class A
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const A& a){
        os << "I am a A!";
        return os;
    }
};
        
class B : public A{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const B& b){
        os << "I am a B!";
        return os;
    }
};
        
class C: public  A{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const C& c){
        os << "I am a C!";
        return os;
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include "classes.h"

int main(){
    std::array<A*, 2> arr;

    arr[0] = new B;
    arr[1] = new C;

    std::cout << *arr[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << *arr[1] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
I am a A!
I am a A!
```

But I would like it to be:

```
I am a B!
I am a C!
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: In this particular case you might want to follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905648/overloading-with-inhertiance-and-polymorphism) and have a single `operator<<` that takes a `const A&` and invokes a virtual helper method

Comment: TL;DR of that dupe: make a polymorphic `print()` or `toString()` function that you call in the `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a virtual function in the base class, like for example:

```
virtual std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const;
```

The function may be `protected`.

And then `override` it in derived classes.

Then, in the friend `operator<<`, call the function.

Comment: Hmm this answer [looks familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40506381/2602718)

Comment: @scohe001 It is funny. It was my answer.:)

Comment: 5 years later I think we can forgive you forgetting you'd answered it already.